# How to download/unzip and install browserstack local in gitlab-ci.yml

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, browserstack

I'm trying to run automated tests via browserstack on private server, tests are executed on Gitlab Ci. Since it is private server I need force local parameter when executing tests. When running from local PC following solution works perfectly:

1. Downloading binary
2. running command./BrowserStackLocal --key  --force-local

I would like to do the same in .gitlab-ci.yml file, but I dont know exactly how to achieve this (how do download unzip and install browserstacklical binary)

This is my .gitlab-ci.yml file right now:

```
stages:
    - e2e_testing

e2e_testing:
    image: node:10.15.3
    stage: e2e_testing
    variables:
        NODE_ENV: dev
    script:
        - apt-get update
        - apt-get install unzip
        - wget http://www.browserstack.com/browserstack-local/BrowserStackLocal-linux-x64.zip
        - unzip BrowserStackLocal-linux-x64.zip
        - ./BrowserStackLocal --key ${BROWSERSTACK_ACCESSKEY} --force-local
        - npm ci
        - npm run test:browserstack

    only:
        - master
    tags:
        - docker
        - build
    artifacts:
        when: always
        paths:
        - reports/
```

Answer (score 1):

You can execute the BrowserStack Local Binary through code using the Local Bindings for Node JS. Reference: https://github.com/browserstack/browserstack-local-nodejs

When using the Local Bindings, the Binary is automatically downloaded and initiated through code itself.

You could try executing the sample test: https://github.com/browserstack/browserstack-local-nodejs/blob/master/node-example.js from your Gitlab CI.

Comment: This is actually a awesome idea thank You. Do You maybe happen to know where in webdriverIO framework should I start and stop this local session ?